# Getting the size of the number

Tags: c#

Which approach is better for getting the size of the number.

```
SomeInt.ToString().Length
```

Or

```
(int)Math.Log10(SomeInt) + 1
```

Comment: @WaiHaLee (int)Math.Log10(Math.Abs(SomeInt)) + 1

Answer (score 4):

If I were you I'd avoid using `Math.Log10` for this purpose. It'll break on zero and negative numbers. The amount of time you spend tracking down bizarro exceptions will exceed the difference in performance by tens of thousands of times.

Comment: Isn't the `ToString` version breaking -as in returning the wrong value- too for negative numbers?

Comment: @mariosangiorgio Depends. If it's for validating how long the textual representation of the number is, then it seems valid to count the `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise you should benchmark it. Intuitively the version using the logarithm should be faster since it's only doing mathematical operations.
Conversely, the version that uses the string has to allocate it, convert the number to the string and then get the length of the string.

To make everything more robust and readable, make sure to introduce a function `int SizeOfNumber(int number)` to wrap your implementation. That would make it easier to understand what the code is doing.

You should also note that none of the approaches work with negative values. The `ToString` version will include the `-` sign and `Log10` isn't defined for zero and for negative numbers.